# In mathematics what does it mean "to occur naturally"?

Tags: terminology

In mathematics, I often meet the expression " 'x' occurs naturally", or " 'x' occurs naturally in 'Y' ".

For example: 
"You should know why eigenvectors and eigenvalues **occur naturally** in linear algebra." 
(Garrity, Thomas A., *All the mathematics you missed: but need to know for graduate school*).

Does it have to do with *physical* nature (as in, mapping well some physics' magnitude behaviour)?

Comment: Occurs "naturally" in your context is because of "as a consequence of an unmentioned relevant (and obvious) theorem"  In your example about the eigenvalues/vectors: They have to exist because a theorem states that and they are consequently needed to prove other theorems that have logical answers which could not be obtained without them. That's how I look at it...

Comment: I think it is a meaningless statement. I would ignore the word 'naturally' in that sentence.

Comment: I agree with copper.hat. I think it is more like a rhetorical device (unlike "is naturally isomorphic to").

Comment: It means that the concept is key to understand several things in a field and/or that it forms part of the answer to several questions in the field. 

I was tempted to write "natural questions in the field", but it's difficult to specify what kind of mahematical cuestions are "natural". It could be how stuff works, how stuff can be described, how stuff relates to other stuff, etc.